# Word for future income that will no longer come

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say I rent out a property for $1,000 a month.

If it is now June, my expected income through to the end of the year is $6,000.

But the contract will end prematurely at the end of September. Which means that the last three months of the year, which could have earned me $3,000, will not.

What is the proper word to describe this sum ($3,000) which had been expected, but is not anymore?

**Note:** I need a way to describe both July-Sep, **and** Oct-Dec.

Comment: It depends whether your renter will be in default of the contract, or if the two of you have just been extending an expired contract month by month. If it's just a matter of hopes and dreams being dashed by financial misfortune, we say "that's life". For the formal terms with respect to default, try Law or Personal Finance SE.

Comment: How can a contract end "prematurely"?  Is the renter defaulting on the lease agreement, or did you just assume they would renew another three months?

Comment: "... the last three months of the year, which **could have** earned me $3,000, will not. ..." -- the "could have" makes it a "notional loss." See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/203758/14666

Answer (score 22):

One word seems difficult, but this is usually described as **lost income** or **lost revenue**. Losing in this case does not mean you had it, and lost it, but rather that you expected to receive it, but you don't.

When someone suffers an injury causing him to be able to work less, we describe the money he could (or would) have earned if he were healthy as *lost income*, to describe income (salary) that he had expected to earn, but he doesn't.

If a fault in a product unexpectedly causes the product not to be sold as much as expected, the manufacturer suffers *lost sales*, leading to *loss of revenue*.

In your situation, I'd say your *projected revenue* is $6000, your *actual revenue* is $3000 and your *lost revenue* is also $3000.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ***shortfall*** comes close to what you mean:

> - a failure to come up to expectation or need
>    *a budget **shortfall***;
> - also : the amount of such failure
>    *a $2 million **shortfall***

Example usage:

> David realizes he has two choices:
>
> 1. Put more money into his existing pension to make up the *shortfall* or,
> 2. Maintain his 4% contributions to his company pension but invest in an alternative solution to make up the *shortfall*.
>
> <sub>[Your Pension Shortfall - Your Retirement Rescue Plan](https://books.google.com/books?id=PiD1BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&dq=shortfall&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR6dj13oLYAhUT2GMKHWZ9A-wQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=shortfall&f=false)</sub>

Comment: The shortfall could also be described as an 'overestimation'.

Answer (score -1):

Deferral

A deferral, in accrual accounting, is any account where the asset or liability is not realized until a future date (accounting period), e.g. annuities, charges, taxes, income, etc.

for more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferral

Comment: In the OP's case, the potential income wasn't deferred. It isn't expected to ever materialise.